# Select n rows from a table per distinct value of a column

Tags: sqlite

I have a huge data base that I want to sample based on one column. 
This column have 10 distinct values, and for each value I want to select 5 rows from the data base.

I've tried this query that works, but is very slow once the data becomes bigger.

```
SELECT *
FROM table AS A
WHERE rowid IN (SELECT rowid FROM table WHERE value=A.value LIMIT 5)
```

```
Input:

SOURCE  DATE            VALUE

IG  2018-12-31  ONE
IG  2019-05-24  TWO
IG  2018-12-31  THREE
TW  2019-06-24  SIX
FB  2019-06-24  FIVE
FB  2019-06-24  FIVE
FB  2019-06-24  ONE
FB  2019-06-24  THREE
FB  2019-06-18  FIVE
FB  2019-06-18  SIX
FB  2019-06-18  ONE
FB  2019-06-18  ONE
IG  2019-06-24  TWO
FB  2019-05-24  THREE
IG  2019-06-24  THREE
RD  2019-06-24  TWO
RD  2019-06-24  SIX
RD  2019-06-24  ONE
TW  2019-06-24  FIVE
FB  2019-06-24  TWO

=============

Output:

SOURCE  DATE            VALUE

FB  2019-06-24  ONE
FB  2019-06-18  ONE
IG  2019-05-24  TWO
RD  2019-06-24  TWO
FB  2019-05-24  THREE
IG  2019-06-24  THREE
FB  2019-06-24  FIVE
FB  2019-06-24  FIVE
FB  2019-06-18  SIX
RD  2019-06-24  SIX
```

Answer (score 0):

Window functions (requires sqlite 3.25 or newer) allow for one easy approach:

```
SELECT source, date, value
FROM (SELECT source, date, value
           , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY value) AS rn
      FROM yourtable)
WHERE rn <= 5
ORDER BY value;
```

picks an arbitrary five rows for each distinct `value`. An index on `value` will be very helpful - and will speed up your version too if you don't already have one.